# Ruby undefined method `[]' substring of an array value

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm working on a script to get the values, parse them, and save them to mongodb. Here's my code:

```
collection.find({}, :projection => {"_id" => 0, "SMSMSG" => 1, "SMSFR" => 1}).each{
  |row|
  dataw = row["SMSMSG"]
  pars = dataw.split(';')
  trans = pars[1]
  loc = pars[3]
  pltn = pars[5]
  timin = pars[6]
  timout = pars[7] #the error occurs here
  transam = pars[8]
  totalh = pars[9] #to here
  puts timout[0,2] #this is error but when
  puts timin[0,2] #there is no error and it displays the result perfectly
}
```

When I reach the 7th and 9th array values of the split string from mongodb result, I get an error. Here's the error:

```
6:in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongo-2.1.0.rc0/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:41:in `block in each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongo-2.1.0.rc0/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:78:in `block in each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongo-2.1.0.rc0/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:78:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongo-2.1.0.rc0/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:78:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mongo-2.1.0.rc0/lib/mongo/collection/view/iterable.rb:40:in `each'
from proc.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa why do i  get that error when i split the character of **timout** variable, **transam** and **totalh** while the other works well

Comment: @Bierc Since you changed the question, now your "question" is not only unclear, but also cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @Stefan that is just a mistype here but in my script pars[6] is working and i can split the value of that variable but the `pars[7]` `pars[8]` `pars[9]` is having an error.

Comment: @Bierc what's the value of `pars`? Could you add a `p pars` after assigning it and show its output?

Comment: @Stefan Okay here is  the raw data from mongodb `"SMSMSG" : "09058000307~PS;OUT;0;null;0000000000000000;10;091120151318;09112015131800;20;0.0"` the value of the `pars[]` are the splitted value from `dataw = row["SMSMSG"]
  pars = dataw.split(';')` my delimiter is `;` so every time i run this script the value of `pars[]` will be copied to the variables that is shown above.

Comment: @Bierc the problem cannot be reproduced with the given data (see my "answer" below) and I'm therefore voting to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` is easy to understand if you read it: you are trying to use the bracket operators on some object that is nil.  You probably think that the object is a String, but it's acutally nil.  You should figure out what object the error is referring to, and then add code to handle the case where that object is nil (or fix the root problem that is causing it to be nil).  One option would be to detect if it is nil and then convert it to the empty string.  Here is one way you could write that:

```
(some_object || '')[0, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks this solves the problem. I'm a beginner sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

[I'm posting this in addition to my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517226/ruby-undefined-method-substring-of-an-array-value/32517865#comment52893758_32517226), because it's too long for a comment.]

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517226/ruby-undefined-method-substring-of-an-array-value#comment52893301_32517226), `row` seems to be a hash:

```
row = {"SMSMSG" => "09058000307~PS;OUT;0;null;0000000000000000;10;091120151318;09112015131800;20;0.‌0"}
```

and `dataw` is a string:

```
dataw = row["SMSMSG"]
#=>"09058000307~PS;OUT;0;null;0000000000000000;10;091120151318;09112015131800;20;0.\u200C0"
```

The only thing that's unusual is the `"0.\u200C0"` at the end, i.e. there's an invisible character [U+200C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) between `0.` and `0`. Maybe this is just due to copy-and-paste.

However, the given code runs *without* errors:

```
pars = dataw.split(';')
trans = pars[1]    #=> "OUT"
loc = pars[3]      #=> "null"
pltn = pars[5]     #=> "10"
timin = pars[6]    #=> "091120151318"
timout = pars[7]   #=> "09112015131800"
transam = pars[8]  #=> "20"
totalh = pars[9]   #=> "0.\u200C0"
puts timout[0,2]
puts timin[0,2]
```

Output:

```
09
09
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution provided by David Grayson it also possible to use the to_s method on the object that you expect to be a string. If it is already a string it will simply return self. nil will return an empty string.

```
"a string".to_s #=> "a string"
nil.to_s        #=> ""
```